# vb odd variable use problem as filepath

Tags: vb.net, overload-resolution

I have this function:

```
Function WriteTextToFile(ByVal data)
    Dim file As New System.IO.StreamWriter("E:\storage.txt")
    file.WriteLine(data)
    file.Close()
End Function
```

I have been trying to adjust it so that the filepath becomes a variable I can pass to allow for multiple storage files. Something like this:

```
Function AppendTextToFile(ByVal data, ByVal path)

        Dim file As New System.IO.StreamWriter(path, True)
        file.WriteLine(data)
        file.Close()

    End Function
```

However while function 1 works, function 2 doesn't - I get this unhelpful error:

```
Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be called without a narrowing conversion:
    'Public Sub New(path As String)': Argument matching parameter 'path' narrows from 'Object' to 'String'.
    'Public Sub New(stream As System.IO.Stream)': Argument matching parameter 'stream' narrows from 'Object' to 'System.IO.Stream'. C:\Users\films ratings\films ratings\Form1.vb
```

I normally work in PHP and I've never seen an error of this nature before. What does it mean and can I re-write the function to get what I want?

Comment: Cheers! Would accept both it if I could :)

Comment: That error seems fairly helpful to me... You can't implicitly convert (or narrow) a parameter of type `Object` to one of type `String`, so the first overload is counted out. And you can't implicitly convert a parameter of type `Object` to one of type `System.IO.Stream`, so the second overload is counted out. Now there are none left to choose from!

Comment: I've never had to deal with any kind of overload before so...

Comment: Well, I don't really know anything about PHP, but if you don't know anything about overloading and you want to start writing programs in VB.NET, I *highly* recommend picking up a book about object-oriented programming (OOP). Understanding that will make your life a *whole lot* easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare the variable `path` as a `String` type and you'll be fine.

The compiler is not able to determine what overload of the constructor should be used because you declared the path parameter as `Object` (that's the default when you don't specify otherwise).

Instead, you should declare your second function like this:

```
Function AppendTextToFile(ByVal data, ByVal path As String)
```

Comment: There's no "probably" about it. Object is the default if you don't specify a particular type in the method declaration.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Yeah, my eyes skipped over the line with the function declaration because it wasn't syntax colored before. 'Probably' was referring to the fact that I was missing the declaration.

Comment: Ah, yeah. I'd forgotten that I fixed the question formatting in between so doing and leaving that comment. ;-) No worries.

Answer (score 4):

You're passing the `path` (and `data`) parameters as an object. By <strike>simply</strike> *always* strongly typing the variables the error here will disappear.

```
Function AppendTextToFile(ByVal data As String, ByVal path As String)

    Dim file As New System.IO.StreamWriter(path, True)
    file.WriteLine(data)
    file.Close()

End Function
```

Comment: +1 And just to reiterate, **always** prefer strongly-typing when possible. VB.NET is not the same as PHP here.